# How to provide user input dynamically in Omnet++?

Tags: c++, input, omnet++

I need to send few messages dynamically from a node Tag to node Anchor and viceversa.
Here i have defined  the msg variable in ned file.

```
simple Tag
{
    parameters:
   // bool sendMsgOnInit = default(false); // whether the module 
should send out a message on initialization
    int limit = default(0);   // another parameter with a default 
value
    string msg3;
    @display("i=block/routing");
    gates:
    input in;
    output out;
}


Below is the ini file.

network = Taganchor
**.messageSent.msg3 = ask
```

Below is the .cc file:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

/**
 * Derive the Tag class from cSimpleModule. In the Taganchor network,
 * both the `tag' and `anchor' modules are Tag objects, created by 
OMNeT++
 * at the beginning of the simulation.
 */
class Tag : public cSimpleModule
{
  private:
    int counter;
  public:
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(Tag);

void Tag::initialize()
{
// Initialize is called at the beginning of the simulation.
// To bootstrap the tag-anchor process, one of the modules needs
// to send the first message. Let this be `init'.
counter = par("limit");
// Am I tag or anchor?
if (strcmp("tag", getName()) == 0) {
    // create and send first message on gate "out". "init" is an
    // arbitrary string which will be the name of the message object.
    cMessage *msg1 = new cMessage("init");
    //cMessage *msg2 = new cMessage("poll");
    send(msg1, "out");


    }
}

void Tag::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
// The handleMessage() method is called whenever a message arrives
// at the module. Here, we just send it to the other module, through
// gate `out'. Because both `tag' and `anchor' does the same, the 
message
// will bounce between the two.


counter++;
//    if (counter == 0) {
//        EV << getName() << "'s counter reached zero, deleting 
message\n";
//        delete msg;
//    }
      if(counter == 1){
        if (strcmp("anchor", getName()) == 0){
       cMessage *msg2= new cMessage("poll");

        send(msg2, "out"); // send out the message

    }

    else {
        
                cMessage *msg3 = new cMessage("response");
                send(msg3, "out");

            }

}
 else if (counter == 2){
     if (strcmp("anchor", getName()) == 0){
        cMessage *msg4 = new cMessage("final");
        send(msg4, "out");
    }

    }
}
```

When I do not initialize msg3 in .cc file and enter the msg3 value when I run the simulation there seems to be no change in simulation.
How to achieve my objective?

Comment: Could you precise what a running OMNeT++ simulation should do with the dynamically input text by user?

Comment: I need to send few messages manually from node A to node B. The simulation is just sending a message from from one node to another and vice versa.

Comment: Could you explain to us what do you mean by "send manually a message"? The topic of the question suggests that you are going to use some text provided manually by user during simulation. However, from the whole question it can be concluded that it is about creating a message in the code and sending it.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ is a C++ library, so anything that works in C++ works in OMNeT++.

There is also a mechanism to ask the user:
https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:parameter-assignments

> Finally, one can explicitly ask the simulator to prompt the user
> interactively for the value (again, provided that interactivity is
> enabled; otherwise this will result in an error): `**.sendInterval = ask`